# Synology DS cloud picture backup

Tags: synchronization, nas, synology

I recently bought a Synology DS 215j which I use to back up my files and generally replace my dropbox.

I've been able to make all the smart phones in my family sync with the NAS, but I have noticed, that it generally mirrors all the photos (or any file for that matter) to both devices. This means that if I delete a picture on my phone, it gets deleted on the NAS. Is there a way to prevent this?

What I really want is for the pictures to get automatically transferred to the disk station and then be deleted on my phone. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Easy fix for the problem you have.

The Software package called BitTorrent Sync.

You can set it to read-only so you keep the data on your nas and delete it on your devices.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the info, I'll certainly look into it! Just for my understanding: This means, I have to delete all my photos by hand on the cellphone, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your question is still up, but what I did is:

- Created a google drive account
- Downloaded the google photos app to my phones
- Installed Cloud Sync on Synology and backed up only the google photo folder created in google drive

Therefore, Google photo has an option to automatically delete photos on the phone, save space, and access photos easily. This would resolve your sync problem